# Error in my SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

So, I've been fighting this code all day. I've tried a ton of things, to no avail.
Therefor, I come here seeking answers.

EDIT:I fixed some of the problems mentioned in the comments. Yet, the problem persists.
The error is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'values where `item_id` = 'Throne' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 10'
at line 1
```

This is my PHP code:

```
    include("config.php");
    include("functions.php");
                if(isset($_GET['name'])){
                    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);


                        $get_rares = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rares WHERE `name` = '".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $rare = mysql_fetch_array($get_rares);
                    if(mysql_num_rows($check) == 0){
                        echo 'The rare '.$id.' doesn\'t exist!<br>';





                    }else{
                        $r = mysql_fetch_array($check);
                        $ids = $r["id"];
                        $name = $r["name"];
                        $value = $r["value"];
                        $lastedited = $r["lastedited"];
                        $catid = $r["catid"];
                        $desc = $r["desc"];
                        $image = $r["image"];
                        $big_image = $r["big_image"];
                        $release_value = $r["release_value"];
                        $releasedate = $r["releasedate"];                       
                    }
                }else{
                    echo 'No rare has been selected to view.<br><br>Click <a href="members.php">here</a> to go to the rare list.';
                }
                ?>          
                <?php $values = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM values where `item_id` = '".$id."' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: What is the error output?

Comment: Added the error output. I knew I forgot something!

Comment: Is `id` an integer? If it is, why are you stripping tags from it? If it’s not, you need quotes in your query. Also, use parametrized queries with PDO (or MySQLi) instead of the `mysql_` set of functions. They’re deprecated.

Comment: You have two 'where's  in your first SQL statement, also you need to put a string value inside quotes while quering

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` is a string, and you need to quote it.

```
$get_rares = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rares WHERE name = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

and

```
$values = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM values WHERE item_id = '$id' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());
```

`WHERE` was also written twice, as @Axel points out.

Answer (score 0):

Omit one of the "where"'s :

```
 "SELECT * FROM rares where WHERE name = ".$id.""
 //                   ***********
```

And:

There are numerous words which can not be taken as column, table, view or whatever name in any query w/o taking precautions to have mysql interpret them properly, look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html)

`values` and `name` are two of them.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, `VALUES` is a keyword, you cannot use is as a field- or table-name without putting it in tick-quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM values where `item_id` = '".$id."' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM `values` where `item_id` = '".$id."' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

`VALUES` is a MySQL keyword and needs to be put in backticks when used as a name:

```
SELECT * FROM `values` WHERE `item_id` = '$id' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

`VALUES` is mysql reserved keyword you need to enclose it with backticks like that

```
     SELECT * FROM `values` where
```

[**mysql reserved keywords**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)